# quiz in javascript, hide one and show another question in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a quiz in jquery, I need to hide the question and show next one. in the end submit the form.

The problem is, it is showing all the questions when I press next instead of one by one.

Any ideas how to solve it?

html

```
<form>


<div class="hideShow">

question a
<input type="radio" name="a" value="l"> answer a1
<input type="radio" name="a" value="d"> answer a2

<input type="button" class="next" value="Next">

</div>


<div class="hideShow">

question b
<input type="radio" name="b" value="l"> answer b1
<input type="radio" name="b" value="d"> answer b2

<input type="button" value="Preview">
<input type="button" value="Next">

</div>


<div class="hideShow">

question c
<input type="radio" name="c" value="l"> answer c1
<input type="radio" name="c" value="d"> answer c2

<input type="button" value="Preview">
<input type="button" value="Next">

</div>


<div class="hideShow">

question d
<input type="radio" name="d" value="l"> answer d1
<input type="radio" name="d" value="d"> answer d2

<input type="button" value="Preview">
<input type="button" value="Next">

</div>


<div class="hideShow">

question e
<input type="radio" name="e" value="l"> answer e1
<input type="radio" name="e" value="d"> answer e2

<input type="button" value="Preview">
<input type="submit" value="Show result">

</div>

</form>
```

jquery

```
$(function() {

    $(".hideShow").first().css("display", "block");


    $( document ).on( "click", ".next", function() {

    $(".hideShow").next().toggle();

    });
});
```

css:

```
.hideShow{
  display:none;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:10px;
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/adzh6t5e/

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".next", function() {
    $(this).closest('.hideShow').hide().next().show();
});
```

Also, in your html only first `Next` button has class `.next`. Add the same class to all next button before testing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the current block of `.hideShow` otherwise it will open all the blocks.

Use `$(this).parent()`, so you can refer to the next's block element and get the next hideShow block.

Here is the jsfiddle with the correction: https://jsfiddle.net/znfeq3ck/